# Capture the results of multiple radiobox selection Django

Tags: django, forms

Total newb here...

I'm making a poll where I display 5 questions on a page.  Each question has 4 radioboxes.

In my django template, I'm looping through a container (latest_poll_list) of all my questions (poll):

```
    <form action="/first/vote/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li>{{ poll.question }}</li>
        {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice{{poll.id}}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
            <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice }}</label><br />
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Lastly how do I return results from multiple questions?  Do I have to put the choice+poll.id into an array/container?

Also, how does django know that forloop.counter refers to the inner loop and not the outer loop?
Thanks for your patience while I ramp up!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a [**`formset`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) or a [**`model formset`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

and the forloop.counter is for the inner most forloop, however you can pass the counter from an outer forloop into the inner forloop using the `{% with %}` tag:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <label>{{ forloop.counter }}</label>
    {% with outside_counter=forloop.counter %}
    {% for subobject in object %}               
    <p>outside: {{ outside_counter }} inside: {{ forloop.counter }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

results:

```
<label>0</label>
<p>outside: 0 inside: 0</p>
<p>outside: 0 inside: 1</p>
<label>1</label>
<p>outside: 1 inside: 0</p>
<p>outside: 1 inside: 1</p>
...
```